# Contact form not sending email (Bootstrap)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, email, html-helper, contact-form

I have created my first website with Bootstrap but having a problem with my contact form because it doesn't actually send the emails to my email address.

I'm not sure what is going on, because I have included my email address and have specified that it needs to be sent 'to' it.

This is the PHP code for the contact form:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "info@cheappockets.com";

    $email_subject = "Contact form enquiry";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the     form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

     if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

   }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

   }

   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

   }

   if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

   }

   if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for your email. We will be in touch with you very soon. 
Kind regards, 
Cheappockets Team



<?php

}

?>
```

How I can correct this so that it will function correctly?

Comment: The actual form is located on [link] (http://cheappockets.com)

Comment: HTML code does not send email in anyway. Doesn't matter if you use bootstrap or not

Comment: @raj454raj Yes I'm aware but it's not allowing me to paste in PHP - apparantly its too long to do so :/

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't send emails. It can only submit form data to a script on a server written in another language like PHP. PHP only runs on a server, it won't run in the browser.

That PHP script (at `www.yoursite.com/submit.php` for example) in turn then takes that information and sends the actual email.

The location of the script you want to submit the form to is added under the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) or [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) pages about forms and actions for more details

Comment: I understand. I have a PHP file but it's not allowing me to post it with the HTML as it's too long. Will change the HTML to PHP now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Iolo but when I use the example from W2Schools, the form is doing more than it was before - it's like progressing to send but doesn't actually send :S really confused about that. Any suggestions?